# Origin of the Maha Sudarshan Mantra?

Tags: vishnu, tantra

My question is about this mantra -

Om Kleem Krishnaaya Govindaaya Gopeejana vallabhaaya

Paraya Param Purushaaya Paramathmaney

Para Karma Manthra Yanthra Thantra

Aabhichara Aushadha Astra Shastraani

Samhara Samhara Mrithyur Mochaya Mochaya

Aum Namo Bhagavathey Maha Sudarshanaaya

Deepthrey Jwaala Pareethaya Sarwa Dhikshobhana Karaaya

Hoom Phat Brahmaney Param Jyothishey Swaaha

In what Purana/Veda is this found? Can you provide more details about its origin and usage? I am looking for original sanskrit documents, in particular any resources about vaishnava tantra would be useful as I believe this mantra falls into that category.

Comment: Origin is pancharatra agamas which are Vaishnava Agmas.

Answer (score 1):

This is a longer version of mantra. there is another famous mantra

> Sahasrara Hum Phat

These mantras and its detailed procedures are explained in Sudarshana kalpam.

I have found only the telugu copy of the book which I am posting here.

[Sri Sudarshana Kalpam](https://ia601903.us.archive.org/20/items/in.ernet.dli.2015.395957/2015.395957.Sudarsana-Kalpam.pdf)

Though I am not sure if this mantra is there or not but most of authentic mantras are given here.

You can refer page 42, 51, and 53.